# Have a Problem to define $OPEN_CL_LIB. How can I do that?

Tags: opencl

I've got a Problem to define $OPEN_CL_LIB. I install this application successfully over sudo apt install ocl-icd-opencl-dev.

After this step, I got the same issue.
"Please set $OPEN_CL_LIB to the path to libOpenCL.so"

How can I resolve this issue? Has anyone an idea?

Best regards
Georg

Comment: In the meantime I figure out a solution. You have to modifiy the .bashrc file in your profil(~/.bashrc) . The path is simular to define likely from a NDK envirement.

e.g.

export OPEN_CL_LIB=$OPEN_CL_LB/usr/lib/... path to the libary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime I figure out a solution. You have to modifiy the .bashrc file in your profil(~/.bashrc) . The path is simular to define likely from a NDK envirement. e.g. export OPEN_CL_LIB=$OPEN_CL_LB/usr/lib/... path to the libary